# 2 possibly related questions - Can't edit profiles - Can't post comments

Tags: ee2, members, comments, comment-form, profile-edit

So working on a blog, easy enough... The client has the following setup:

- Windows IIS7
- EE v2.5.5 - Build Date: 20121220
- Site located at www.mydomain.com (domain-1)
- Admin on another site like sub-domain at ee.mydomain.com (domain-2)
- The Admin is behind a firewall with no access to the public

Issue 1:

- Can't access member profiles

I have accounts set up on the site and have the following link for the users to edit their info:

```
{if logged_in}
    Welcome <a href="{path='member/profile'}">{logged_in_screen_name}</a><br /><a href="{path='LOGOUT'}">Logout</a>
{/if}
```

When I click on the name, I get the following message:

```
The following errors were encountered

The page you requested was not found
```

However, the link looks legit:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/S=7d3285379e0387a32aad7de52b6aac94cd79b19f/member/profile
```

---

Issue 2:

- I can't comment on the threads

I have the following code set up for commenting: (Note this is after the closing `{/exp:channel:entries}` tag

```
{exp:comment:entries channel="blog_post" url_title="{segment_3}" sort="asc" limit="100"}
    {if count==1} {!-- This way we wont open the div or unordered list unless there are comments to display --}
        <!-- comments list -->
        <div id="comments-wrap">
            <h4 class="heading">{total_results} Comments</h4>
            <ol class="commentlist">
    {/if}
    <li class="comment even thread-even depth-1" id="li-comment-{count}">
        <div id="comment-{count}" class="comment-body cf">
            <img src="{exp:ce_gravatar:single email="{email}"}" alt="{name}" class='avatar avatar-35 photo' height='35' width='35'/>
            <div class="comment-author vcard">{name}</div>
            <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
                <span class="comment-date">{comment_date format="%Y %m %d"}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="comment-inner">
                {comment}
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    {if count==total_results} {!--close the list after the last comment --}
            </ol>
        </div>
    {/if}
{/exp:comment:entries}
<!-- ENDS comments list --> 
<h4>Add Your Comment</h4>
{exp:comment:form channel="blog_post" url_title="{segment_3}" form_id="comment_form"}
    {if logged_out}
        Must be logged in to comment.<br>
    {if:else}
        <p><label for="user_comment_area">Comment:</label></p>
        <p><textarea name="user_comment_area" style="width: 542px;" rows="10">{comment}</textarea></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" name="save_info" value="yes" {save_info} /> Remember my personal information</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" name="notify_me" value="yes" {notify_me} /> Notify me of follow-up comments?</label></p>
        {if captcha}
            <p><label for="captcha">Please enter the word you see in the image below:</label></p>
            <p>{captcha}</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="captcha" value="{captcha_word}" maxlength="20" /></p>
        {/if}
        <p><input type="submit" value="" class="blue-submit"></p>
    {/if}
{/exp:comment:form}
```

The logic is fine as in not displaying unless logged in. However, when I am logged in and add a comment, it appears to accept the comment and then refresh showing nothing. Again, this should be correct because I want to moderate comments, but when I go to the comment module there is nothing there. There is also nothing in the DB in the comment table.

*** EDIT ***

So it appears that there is an issue with permissions on the current setup. They have set up two separate app pools with the admin pool having all permissions to the system (domain-2) and the user app pool having permission to only the site (domain-1).

It acts like everything is hunky dory but nothing is being written. They don't want to "expose" access to the system folder and want to keep it on a separate domain. Is it possible to function completely this way or am I hosed here?

*** EDIT IMAGES ***

Here are the settings for the channel and user group. However, this also has the same result for SA accounts.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Anna_MediaGirl](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/28/anna-mediagirl) for helping through this. It seems like the issue is with the removal of index.php in my URLs. When I went back to the general settings and replaced that for the default file, i worked fine. I guess this puts me on another mission to find a better removal of index.php for IIS servers.   (Ick)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your member group permissions aren't set up correctly.

Make sure [**Can submit comments**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups_edit.html#can-submit-comments) and **[Can view public profiles are](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups_edit.html#can-view-public-profiles)** enabled for the member group.

Comment: Both are on.   ;)

Comment: Does "member/profile" exist as a template group and template or are you trying to access EE's native profile template?

Comment: What is a real example URL for the page with the comment form?

Comment: Native profile... I got them to change permissions on the app pools and got the profile access to work. (Just now)

Comment: Comment form still not working though. I even turned off moderation. I wish I had a real world example to link to, but everything is still locked behind their firewall.

Comment: I don't need a real URL, just post the URL with the real segments and change the domain name to whatever. I just want to see how the segments are being used.

Comment: gotcha... the comment form is on a page like this:    ht tp: //w ww.thesite.com/blog/the-article-url-title

Comment: Your code is looking at segment_3 for the url_title but it's actually in segment_2. Change that and your code should work correctly.

Comment: Tried that this morning... no dice. I have tried that, last_segment, nothing, ... running at a loss on this one.  ;)